# C++Template in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I want something like this:

```
public abstract class ListenerEx<LISTENER, PARENT> implements LISTENER {
    PARENT parent;
    public ListenerEx(PARENT p) {
        parent = p;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't compile. Is there a better solution?
Is there something in Java like C++ template that would do check syntax after template deduction?

---

The following explains why I need such a ListenerEX class,
if you already know what it is, you don't need to read the following.

I have a main window, and a button on it, and I want to get access to some method of the main window's within the listener:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    public void doSomething() {
        /* ... */
    }
    public void doSomethingElse() {
        /* ... */
    }

    private JButton button;

    public MainWindow() {
        button = new JButton(...);
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                doSomething();
                doSomethingElse();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This would compile but does not work properly all the time.
(Why would it compile when the ActionListener does not have doSomething() method?)

Of course we can do it like this:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    public void doSomething() {
    }
    public void doSomethingElse() {
    }

    private JButton button;

    public MainWindow() {
        button = new JButton(...);
        add(button);

        class ActionListener1 implements ActionListener {
            MainWindow parent;
            public ActionListener(MainWindow p) {
                parent = p;
            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                parent.doSomething();
                parent.doSomethingElse();
            }
        }
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener1(this));
    }
}
```

However I hate this style ...

So I tried:

```
public abstract class ActionListenerEx<P> implements ActionListener {
    P parent;
    public ActionListenerEx(P p) {
        parent = p;
    }
}
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    public void doSomething() {
    }
    public void doSomethingElse() {
    }

    private JButton button;

    public MainWindow() {
        button = new JButton(...);
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListenerEx<MainWindow>(this) {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                parent.doSomething();
                parent.doSomethingElse();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But there's lots of Listeners beside the ActionListener ...

```
public abstract class ActionListenerEx<LISTENER, PARENT> implements LISTENER {
    PARENT parent;
    public ActionListenerEx(PARENT p) {
        parent = p;
    }
}
```

However, it won't compile ...

I am fresh at Java, and I wonder if there's already better solution.

Comment: You are looking for Java generics. I don't really know much about it but you should be fine with a little bit of googling.

Comment: Swing code tends to be a bit of messy glue logic.  This is why a number of GUI builders tend to hide these details.  I suggest you look at what can be done with your IDE. Netbeans has a nice one.

Comment: I got baffled people don't realize that what you're trying to do cannot be done in standard Java. I'm also looking for a decent template/macro system for meta-programming Java, not the shitty typecast-only one included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would it compile when the
>   ActionListener does not have
>   doSomething() method?)

Because the containing class has the doSomething() method. There's an implicit `MainWindow.this` prepended there.

What's wrong with your first version? It seems fine. Other than that, what's your question? You're all over the place and posted a bunch of code.

Comment: Sounds like a problem elsewhere. What's "sometimes" and what do you expect it to do and what's it doing?

Comment: I'm not sure when it happens, and probably it is a bug.

Comment: What? What happens that you say it doesn't work sometimes, and what does it do that you say it doesn't work?

Comment: There is a String declared in the MainWindow Class, and if you try to access it in the "actionPerformed" Method, it returns null.

Comment: "There is a String declared in the MainWindow Class, and if you try to access it in the "actionPerformed"..." 
It works well now, but not always... Thank you for patience.

Comment: Can you post more code that actually demonstrates the error? Right now we have no idea.

Comment: I don't know how to generate this error. I don't have this problem while my friend has, so I told him to use version 2. So maybe it came from other places. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote I want something like this:

```
public abstract class ListenerEx<LISTENER, PARENT> implements LISTENER {
PARENT parent;
public ListenerEx(PARENT p) {
    parent = p;
}
```

}

But it doesn't compile. Is there a better solution? Is there something in Java like C++ template that would do check syntax after template deduction?

It doesn't compile because u can't parametrize with hardcoded classes/interfaces.
So, `ListenerEx<LISTENER, PARENT>` is meaningless. what you want is

```
ListenerEx<L extends LISTENER, P extends PARENT>
```

ugh... so not used to posting on stackoverflow

Comment: I'm sorry, but LISTENER and PARENT are parameters, not class names.

Comment: The problem is (the compiler says) you must "implements" a hardcoded class name. like this "abstract class ActionListenerEx<PARENT> implements ActionListener"

Comment: u have to specify a type for the parameters. so if u want to parametrize ListenerEx with 2 parameters, the first a listener and the second a parent, then u have to do it the way i showed earlier. L extends LISTENER. If LISTENER is not a class or an interface, u have to replace that with whatever class/interface u need. That will make L of type LISTENER. Similarly P and PARENT

Comment: Actually, I would like something like this: #define F(L) public abstract class ListenerEx<P> implements L

Answer (score 0):

Falmarri is correct. Your intial version of code with the Annonymous Inner Class defn of ActionListener is fine. If ur code doesnt work correctly the error is not coming from there.

I notice that u have the ActionListener in the constructor of MainWindow. Make sure that your instance variables are initialized before the doSomething...() methods are called inside the ActionListener.

Another word of extreme caution I'd like to give u is that u r using a generalization relationship between MainWindow and JFrame (parent-child relationship). keep in mind that if u extend JFrame, u inherit all of the methods defined in JFrame. in many cases (esp ones involving gui's) people use a generalization relationship when in fact, they want a composition relationship. It'd be better to have an instance variable that points to a JFrame rather than make it a sub-class of JFrame.

Long story short, check to see if u can write ur code w/o making MainWindow a child of JFrame. if u can, u shouldn't make MainWindow a child of JFrame.